# Taylor expansion in momentum integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, integration, thermal-field-theory

On Ashok Das' book "Finite temperature field theory", page 21, the book introduces the thermal mass correction to scalar field.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta m^2 & =\Delta m_0^2+\Delta m_T^2 \\
& =\frac{\lambda}{4} \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\omega_k}+\frac{\lambda}{2} \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\omega_k} \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\beta \omega_k}-1}
\end{aligned} \tag{1.48}
$$
where
$$
\omega_k=\left(\vec{k}^2+m^2\right)^{1 / 2} \tag{1.45}
$$
The second term in (1.48) is the thermal correction to scalar mass.
Then, the book says:

> "with a bit of analysis, it can be shown that at high temperature, the temperature dependent part of the mass correction has the form"
> $$
> \Delta m_T^2=\frac{\lambda}{24 \beta^2}+O(\beta m)=\frac{\lambda T^2}{24}+O\left(\frac{m}{T}\right). \tag{1.49}
> $$

I am troubled how this taylor expansion is carried out. I know this is a little bit math problem, but troubled me a lot. I've tried that the leading term of (1.49) is just the result of $m\rightarrow 0$ limit. But, how can we obtain the $\mathcal{O}(\beta m)$?